# .Net Core 2.2 / Kestrel / Swagger disabling Chunking / Encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I'm being a REST api in .Net Core 2.2 / Kestrel / Swagger 3 (OpenAPI). I've noticed in Fiddler that my responses are all marked as Encoded with the yellow banner, have Chunked Encoding enabled and the Json is littered with 5J, etc. How can I disable that?

I've seen a few threads on SO, but they are for older versions...

Also, my guess is that I'd like to do this through middleware some how... so I don't have to change any controls and Swagger all plugs in through that.

There was one SO response that linked to a GitHub project that supposedly did it, but the project was deleted.

It comes back like this in Fiddler (with the 51 and the 0):

```
51
{
  "": [
    "Content-Type must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded."
  ]
}
0
```

Header:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcR2lsIFJvc2luXERvY3VtZW50c1xWaXN1YWwgU3R1ZGlvIDIwMTdcUHJvamVjdHNcRFRNUzJcdG9rZW4=?=
Server: Kestrel
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: do you have a [mcve] we could look at?

Comment: @JohnB I can't give you a "minimal" example of a swagger site lol... but I've updated the post to include the response header and body.

Comment: To an end client application (which Fiddler isn't), chunked encoding shouldn't change the data. Have you tried testing with an actual client? Even [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) would do.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have not tried with Postman. From what I'm reading, the way swagger and the controllers are set up, they just write out the response body without a content length, so kestrel makes it chunked.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Also, just to point out... Fiddler doesn't report chunked encoding on any other site :).

Comment: I added an answer, but why do you think chunked encoding is a problem? It's very unlikely to be causing any issues.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee is getting at the same thing I am. It doesn't matter what Fiddler says. It only matters how an actual client application behaves. If a client application doesn't have any problems, then there is no problem to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering/) package contains a middleware that will buffer your responses. Just call `UseResponseBuffering()` on your application builder during start up configuration.

Note that your responses still may be chunked by anything that's sitting in front of Kestrel (IIS, nginx, etc.).

As an aside, having your responses chunked shouldn't be causing any problems, unless you have some strange non-conformant HTTP client communicating with it. The HTTP stack of anything hitting your server should be decoding the chunking behind the scenes.

Comment: One of the issues with the default chunking is there is latency on small JSON payloads which would do better without chunking. Another issue is not being able to determine the Content-Length which some front-end apps rely on to communicate loading progress.

Comment: Note that as of 2022, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering/ was deprecated. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27470 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75270177/what-is-the-replacement-of-iapplicationbuilder-useresponsebuffering-starting-fro