# What is the replacement of IApplicationBuilder.UseResponseBuffering starting from .net Core 2+

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, httpresponse, buffering, asp.net-core-middleware

Since the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering` has been deprecated after .net Core 1.1, what is the best practice to restore the feature provided by `IApplicationBuilder.UseResponseBuffering()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27470) said, this is feature may be released at the .net 8.

Besides, if you want to disable or enable the response buffering, I suggest you could consider using the [IHttpResponseBodyFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.ihttpresponsebodyfeature?view=aspnetcore-7.0). It contains the buffering settings for response body.